# Cannot change font in WinForms MonthCalendar control

Tags: winforms, fonts, monthcalendar

```
MonthCalendar1.Font = newFont
```

doesn't work if we assign a new font. The same default MS Sans Serif 8.25 is used.

Is it a know issue, and how to overcome it?

Comment: [Changing font of `MonthCalendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a [known](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/0082c9e8-e697-484f-a35a-b25731ff7f45/) [issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d18ed2ca-411c-4588-9933-858751c3d2e6/), but apart from turning off `Application.EnableVisualStyles` there's no way around it.