# How to make MonthCalendar only display a single month when enlarged?

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

If I enlarge a `MonthCalendar` it starts to display multiple month calendars at the same time:

[image: Picture of what happens]

Is there a way to enlarge a `MonthCalendar` so that it keeps displaying a calendar for only a single month?

Comment: There is no "enlarge". You are talking about the dimensions. Click on `CalendarDimensions` and check the info about it at the very bottom of your properties. Its `the count of columns and rows of MONTHS`. So its not about the size. Its more about the count of calendars.

Comment: You can [change the font size of `MonthCalendat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

You can force to display only one month by setting the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` properties to the first and last day of the month.

I don't think there's a way to make the month font larger. There's a `SingleMonthSize` property but it's readonly. You could make your own user control to display single month with custom font size.

Comment: You can [change the font size of `MonthCalendat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834)