# How to remove the border of a DateTimePicker Control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, datetimepicker

Is it possible to remove the border of DateTimePicker?
Because I'm trying to make it border-less for design.

Comment: What are you using Windows Forms, WPF or ?

Comment: Windows Form Bro

Comment: In addition to Jimi's answer, you may want to take a look at this [Flat DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092509/3110834). You can download/clone the project and add it to your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using a Custom Control, derived from DateTimePicker.
It adds a few public properties that allow to change the Color and style of the Control's Border.

- **`BorderColor`** sets the Color of the Border. It defaults to `Color.Transparent`.
- **`BorderStyle`** sets the Border Style (Solid, Dotted, Dashed etc.). It defaults to `Solid`.
- **`BorderColorUseBackColor`** is a switch, used to set the `BorderColor` Property to the Control's `BackColor` value. When set to `True`, the `BorderColor` cannot be changed. The value set is however cached and will be set when the Property is set to `False`.

To draw the Border as defined by these properties, the Control overrides [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.wndproc) to handle the [WM_PAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message and draws a custom Border using the standard [ControlPaint.DrawBorder()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder) method.

If you want to *hide* the Control's Border, you can just set `BorderColorUseBackColor = True` (as described, the `BorderColor` is fixed to the Control's `BackColor`, hence it's not visible).

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<DesignerCategory("Code"), ToolboxItem(True)>
Public Class DateTimePickerEx
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Const WM_PAINT As Integer = &HF

    Private m_BorderStyle As ButtonBorderStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid
    Private m_BorderColor As Color = Color.Transparent
    Private m_CurrentBorderColor As Color = Color.Transparent
    Private m_UseBackColor As Boolean = False

    <DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "Transparent")>
    Public Property BorderColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_BorderColor
        End Get
        Set
            If m_UseBackColor Then
                m_CurrentBorderColor = Value
                Return
            End If
            If m_BorderColor <> Value Then
                m_BorderColor = Value
                Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue(GetType(ButtonBorderStyle), "Solid")>
    Public Property BorderStyle As ButtonBorderStyle
        Get
            Return m_BorderStyle
        End Get
        Set
            If m_BorderStyle <> Value Then
                m_BorderStyle = Value
                Invalidate()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <DefaultValue(GetType(Boolean), "False")>
    Public Property BorderColorUseBackColor As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_UseBackColor
        End Get
        Set
            If Value Then
                m_CurrentBorderColor = m_BorderColor
                BorderColor = BackColor
                m_UseBackColor = Value
            Else
                m_UseBackColor = Value
                BorderColor = m_CurrentBorderColor
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)

        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_PAINT
                If IsHandleCreated Then
                    Using g = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(Me.Handle)
                        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, ClientRectangle, m_BorderColor, m_BorderStyle)
                    End Using
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```