# C# - How can let my month Calendar look like in Design

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I make an Application simmilar to Microsoft ToDo.

I made an User Control, where the Calender is in.

When i have it in the Design, it looks like this:
https://ibb.co/XD0Wyj5

But when i start the Programm, it looks like this: https://ibb.co/vv30xrw

I tried it with

> Application.EnableVisualStyles();

but it still looks like this.

What can i do to have the Design in the started Program?

Comment: Try switching visual styles off: `Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;`

Comment: You don't need to disable the visual styles for the whole application, instead, you may want to [disable visual styles for the MonthCalendar control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `VisualStyleState` reference - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/VisualStyles/VisualStyleState.cs,01ad4fcb5f9ea430,references

The visual styles are not enabled when `VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled` is assigned to
`Application.VisualStyleState`