# Size MonthCalendar C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, monthcalendar

I am developing a project for my class that involves using the MonthCalendar Object. I would like to resize the MonthCalendar without displaying more than one month at a time.

[image: Form with MonthCalendar Resized incorrectly]

I would like it to look like this with one month displayed,

[image: Form with MonthCalendar wrong size]

I have googled many methods of disabling the style of the MonthCalendar,

- Disabling Windows Visual Styles
- Downloading new themes

All of the solutions I have tried have either not worked or out of date and are not compatable with Visual Studio 2022

Any tips would be helpful, or upto date advice.

Comment: ['Change month calendar size'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834) works, but it requires disabling visual styles for the control.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A classic example of cases where the Community Bot doesn't work.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how do I disable visual styles, sorry for the late response I forgot i posted this

Comment: Look at the link in the first comment