# why do i see two different calendar layouts using windows forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, calendar, datetimepicker

i have a very old projects, in one of those the calendar layouts are different on two different forms. Not sure why. i had a chance to dig through entire code. couldnt figure out. May i know what changes the layout as below. i have use datapicker controls of windows forms. the first image is of default view that i most commonly see. but not sure what changes make the calendar layout to look as second image. Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

[image: Calendar Layout 1]
[image: Calendar Layout 2]

Had looked through the entire code base to see if there is any configuration settings but couldnt find out.

Comment: Are the two examples from different windows versions? (i.e two other PC stations)

Comment: One is the themed look one is the classic look. Somewhere in the startup code is a `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` missing?

Comment: Or maybe the [theme has been turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54912594/3110834) for DateTimePicker?

Comment: @Ralf you were right. in one of my startup project Application.EnableVisualStyles() line was missing. Adding it fixed the issue.